# Compress traffic when copying a lot of files over network between two Windows machine?

Tags: windows, powershell

The tools under unix/linux, e.g., scp, rsync, etc., support compression when copying files. Does any Windows (Server) tools do the compression when copying?

I will need to copy 5TB of text files which can be highly compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in PowerShell 5.0 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-5.0) there is the Compress-Archive command.

The script below will allow you to compress the files while moving them:

```
Compress-Archive -Path C:\Origination\Test_Folder -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath D:\Destination\Test_Folder.zip
```

For earlier PowerShell versions you can try the article here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-archive-a-folder-and-copy-to-server/ which is similar but uses .NET.